# xmlNode to objects

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlnode

I have been working with a 3rd party java based REST webservice, that returns an array of xmlNodes.

The xmlNode[] respresent an object and I am trying to work out the best way to Deserialize the xmlNode[] in the object? is it to build up a xmlDocument first and the Deserialize ?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have the WCF Rest Starter Kit preview installed, there's a neat trick:

- open Visual Studio
- select your XML node contents (the XML that makes up one of your nodes) and copy it to the clipboard
- from your "Edit" menu in Visual Studio, pick "Paste XML as Types"

This will paste your XML that's on the clipboard into your project as a C# class that is capable of deserializing that exact XML. Pretty nifty!

See these blog posts about it:

- [Aaron Skonnard: WCF REST Starter Kit: Paste XML as Types](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2009/03/16/wcf-rest-starter-kit-paste-xml-as-types.aspx)
- ["Paste XML as Types" in REST Starter Kit](http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2009/03/16/paste-xml-as-types-in-rest-starter-kit.aspx)

That should save you a lot of typing and make life a lot easier!

**UPDATE:**
OK, you already have your classes generated from the XML you get back. Now you need to convert a `XmlNode` to your class.

You'll have to do something like this:

```
private static T ConvertNode<T>(XmlNode node) where T: class
{
    MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream();

    StreamWriter stw = new StreamWriter(stm);
    stw.Write(node.OuterXml);
    stw.Flush();

    stm.Position = 0;

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T result = (ser.Deserialize(stm) as T);

    return result;
}
```

You need to write the XML representation (property `.OuterXml`) of the `XmlNode` to a stream (here a `MemoryStream`) and then use the `XmlSerializer` to serialize back the object from that stream.

You can do it with the generic method and call

```
 Customer myCustomer = ConvertNode<Customer>(xmlNode);
```

or you could even turn that code into either an extension method on the `XmlNode` class so you could write:

```
 Customer myCustomer = xmlNode.ConvertNode<Customer>();
```

Marc

Comment: Hi, I already have the objects from the xsd so I really dont nee to do this step. I am wanting to learn whats the best way to go from xmlNodes[] (serialized object).

Answer (score 19):

Maybe this is too late to answer here but it will help others:

Here is the solution you will be able to `Deserialize` from the XML node.

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

 XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SystemInfo");

 XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SystemInfo));
 
 using(XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlNode)) {
     SystemInfo syso =(SystemInfo)serial.Deserialize(reader);
 }
```

The first load the XML to `XmlDocument Object` and then find the parent node you will wish to deserialize just like I want **SystemInfo** object node from all the XML document.

Once you find that create an `XmlSerializer` object with the specific class type you will wish to.

Now just pass the `reader` (created with `using`) to the **Deserialize** method, you will get the objects populated in the class object just like I populated `syso` object with XML values.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Don't forget that XmlNodeReader needs disposing. Better to use a `using (XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlNode)` block.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the built in System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer class in .NET.  A google search on XmlSerializer will provide a ton of tutorials that you can use to find a tutorial that works for you.

Comment: Obvious and not useful. Of course I need XMLSerializer, but I have an XML node and not a string or a stream. Luckily, a google search provides the other useful answer to this question